# Peewee: change "Id" field with another name

Tags: python, peewee

Is there a way on a Peewee model to change the default primary key named "id" into another name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple ways...

Auto-incrementing integer field named "pk":

```
class MyModel(Model):
    pk = PrimaryKeyField()
    other_field = TextField()
```

Varchar primary key:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    data = CharField(primary_key=True)
```

Multi-column primary key:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    key = CharField()
    value = CharField()

    class Meta:
        primary_key = CompositeKey('key', 'value')
```

Comment: Thanks! peewee's awesome